# Indexing Azure WAD logs data to extract fields on import to splunk

Tags: logging, azure, splunk

we have data that comes from windows azure WADLogs, which I export comma separated and ends up looking like this:

> `"0635010205200000000","d921c47290f944a69c3394373b5c5988___Pricing.Api___Pricing.Api_IN_0___0000000001652031516___WADLogsLocalQuery",2013-04-08T12:24:04.8000293Z,635010205409475113,"deploymentid","Role","Role_IN_0",5,2,608,3232,"TimeTaken::16043 ms to perform Action::'some action'; TraceSource 'PricingApiTrace' event"`

I want to extract fields called TimeTaken with a value of 16043 and Action with a value of 'some action'.

I can change the format of the bit starting '"TimeTaken ' if that would make things easier, and was hoping, after reading that :: automatically created fields that using the format above would allow the indexing to create the fields automatically, but it seems that this is not the case.

Any pointers?

Comment: I'd ask on the splunk help pages but it won't let me until I've verified email address, which I hav and have the badge for but it doesn't seem to recognize that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two [search-time field extractions](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/5.0.2/Knowledge/Addfieldsatsearchtime) to create fields for `TimeTaken` and `Action`.

You will need to define a regular expression for each field, this should be straightforward given the format you describe.

Comment: thanks @seedhead.  I know I can do this but I have a lot of events and I'd like to create the fields at index time so the searches were then quick, rather than have to run the run the regexes everytime, which I think this would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: Field extraction, performed at index time, can degrade performance at both index time and search time, Splunk is heavily optimised to handle field extractions at search time and as a general rule they recommend you do this.

A further advantage of doing this at search time is flexibility, as you can change your regex at any time without having to worry about updating fields that have already been indexed.

Comment: ok, thanks.  does it make a difference if I know the data will be indexed once and then will never change? so i don't care about index time and would happily sacrifice for search time improvements.  But I'll give this a go on my full dataset and see what it gives me.

Comment: Potentially. Give it a go with just search time first, since you can always add index time extractions later (and backfilling older data with this field). If you have bad search performance, I'd look at how your indexers and search heads are configured first, since other queries are likely to be slow as well.